# Cant get tomcat to show webapp from deployed .war file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I followed a tutorial and am trying to learn to make my own web app.  I am using Tomcat 8.0.47 and Spring MVC.  Issue is I can go to localhost:8080 and see that the server is on but I cant see my basic webapp running when visiting localhost:8080/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial  page.  I made a WAR file and dropped it into the /webapps/ folder inside tomcat folder and console shows that it deployed the war file.  Any help is appreciated.

I am following this tutorial:  http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

rather than paste all the files I decided to link the guide.  My set up is the same but cant figure out why it is not working. thanks.

Comment: What is a error that you are getting?

Comment: please share the error. If you are lauching the tomcat from eclipse share the console log. or if your tomcat is standalone or a service, please check the tomcat installation directory/logs/catalina.date.log. Also share the error displayed in browser when you launch your url.(specifically the error code.(eg: 403, 500 etc))

Comment: Also try with "localhost:8080/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial/". the slash at the end is important

Comment: http://localhost:8080/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial/  returns HTTP 404 error  

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: standalone 

06-Nov-2017 20:40:12.751 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 512 ms
06-Nov-2017 20:42:02.790 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Users\DinoJew\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.0.47\webapps\CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial.war
06-Nov-2017 20:42:02.848 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Users\DinoJew\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.0.47\webapps\CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial.war has finished in 58 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I needed to add the CATALINA_HOME system variable to properly setup my tomcat server